# error : 'module' object is not callable when using logmmse

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, audio, processing

I am trying to reduce noise in my audio_file and want to have an output file which doesn't contain noise, and I use the [logmmse](https://pypi.org/project/logmmse/) library:

I use this code:

```py
import wavio
import numpy as np
from logmmse import logmmse_from_file
import logmmse

r = wavio.read('03-01-02-02-01-01-01(read).wav')

y,sr = librosa.load('03-01-02-02-01-01-01(read).wav')

#print(y)
import numpy as np
A = np.asarray(y)
```

but I have this error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable!

can you help me please?

```py
#print(A)
logmmse(A, r.rate, output_file = 'log.wav')
```

Comment: I assume you have to do `logmmse.logmmse(A, r.rate, output_file = 'log.wav')`

Comment: thank you , it's  working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you are trying to call the module itself. I suppose what you're trying to do is use the `logmmse` function inside the `logmmse` module, so you should do:

```
logmmse.logmmse(A, r.rate, output_file = 'log.wav')
```